# htaccess redirect https traffic to a specific folder?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl

I am hosting my website on godaddy and recently purchased an SSL cert so I can also run https traffic.  However, I want all https traffic to go to a specific folder that regular http cannot get to.  In addition, I don't want the specific folder to be a sub-folder of the main http document root.

GoDaddy cPanel folder structure:

```
/home/myAccountFolder/
    /cache
    /logs
    /public_html
    /private_html
    ...
```

By default, all standard http traffic for "www".foo.com will go to /public_html - but how can I get all traffic for https://api.foo.com to map to the /private_html folder?

I am told that .htaccess can do this but can't seem to locate how to do this.   I know I could redirect https to /home/myAccountFolder/public_html/secure, but I want it going to /home/myAccountFolder/private_html - a completely different root folder.

Also, I don't have access to the server configuration or (that I am aware of) have the ability to create/manage virtual hosts within GoDaddy's cPanel enviornment.  All I can do is control directories and what goes into my websites .htaccess file.

Comment: Without access to server config you cannot use any path outside `DocumentRoot`

Comment: @anubhava bummer.  I thought this was going to be the answer. Guess I have to do /home/myAccountFolder/public_html/secure - but how can I prevent any http traffic from getting to the secure folder?  More specifically, I only want traffic destined for https://api.foo.com to have access to the /public_html/secure folder.  If its not coming in on that host/domain request it can't get to that folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your site root .htaccess you can use this rule to redirect `api.foo.com` to `secure/` folder:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api\. [NC]
RewriteRule !^api/ api%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

Inside your `api/.htaccess` you can use this rule to allow only `http://api.foo.com`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^api\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ -  [F]

# rest of the rules
```

Comment: thanks for this.  I am testing various urls and so far its looks like redirects are working.  However, currently, https://www.foo.com is redirecting to https://api.foo.com and  http://www.foo.com/api is redirecting to https://api.foo.com/api - is it possible to prevent those inbound requests from redirecting? I only want requests for https://api.foo.com to be able to get to the /api folder

Comment: What should happen when request comes as `http://foo.com/api`? Should it cause redirect to `http://api.foo.com/` or should ut cause 403?

Comment: I would want it to cause a 403.  The only thing I want getting to the api folder is traffic meant for https://api.foo.com, 'api' folder.  I guess to better clarify only www is for http, and api is for https.  Thus https://www.foo.com would be a 403 as well as http://api.foo.com.  trying to prevent cross pollination.  :-)